# PHP fgetcsv: Strange characters when reading in MAC OS exported CSV File

Tags: php, macos, encoding, csv, character-encoding

I'm working with a CSV file exported from a MAC OS - File Maker Pro program. The CSV seems to be formatted properly. It imports into PHP and into my MySQL database ok. It also imports into my Ubuntu OS using LibreOffice Calc. But, in all cases I end up with strange characters. It's supposed to be a UTF-8 charset, but I'm not sure. Can anyone help explain what kind of transformation is occuring?

Examples:

... Herald Print., [1880â€™s?]. First and only edition ...

....excellent relic of this manufacturerâ€™s involvement with....

Edit:

Looking at part of the above:

```
[1880’s?]

manufacturer’s

lost.




od -ctx1 part.txt

0000000   [   1   8   8   0 342 200 231   s   ?   ]  \r   m   a   n   u

         5b  31  38  38  30  e2  80  99  73  3f  5d  0d  6d  61  6e  75

0000020   f   a   c   t   u   r   e   r 342 200 231   s  \r   l   o   s

         66  61  63  74  75  72  65  72  e2  80  99  73  0d  6c  6f  73

0000040   t   .      \v  \r  \r

         74  2e  20  0b  0d  0d

0000046
```

Comment: Is the output's encoding defined as the same as the encoding of the text?

Comment: Try looking at a dump of the data using something like `od -ctx1 file.txt`, which will show you C-style escaped characters along with a hex dump.  With that, you should be able to determine whether this is UTF8 or something else.

Comment: Open the CSV in a text editor and play around with letting the text editor interpret the file in different encodings. When it looks ok, you have found the encoding the file is actually in.

Answer (score 0):

The encoding is indeed UTF8 and your quotation mark is right there:

http://www.tachyonsoft.com/uc0020.htm

The transformation you see appears to be UTF8 interpreted as ISO-8859-1[5] or Latin1, after you read it, so check that your MySQL is using UTF8 as charset and that the extraction stage keeps it in UTF8 (e.g., if you sent the data to a webpage advertising ISO-8859-15, you'd see exactly that - an Euro sign followed by garbage).